# Is there a way to run EWF on normal Windows 7 (not Windows 7 Embedded)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-embedded-7

I'm using Windows 7 Embedded in a computer just because I want EWF (Enhanced Write Filter).

I'm having some problems running my application running on Windows 7 Embedded, so I want to know if it possible run EWF in a normal Windows 7, and if so how can I do it?

Or is there an alternative to EWF that does the same job?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install EWF on Windows 7 Home/Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate.  If your application is compatible with Windows 8.1, Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro is "regular" Windows with the embedded features you can turn on.  The Unified Write Filter (UWF) is a bit different, but is close enough to test workflows without having to worry about missing WES7 components.

Comment: But this Unified Write Filter just have on Windows 8 right? And some solution fot the 7?

Comment: You could build a WES7 image with the "Application Compatibility" profile.  It basically puts all the (regular) components into the build. Add EWF and you could test using that.

Comment: Yes I know, but as I wrote in my question it dons't work with W7E even with the "Application Compatibility".

Comment: There isn't a "regular" Windows 7 with EWF, only Windows 8/8.1, which is why I suggested it as a stand-in if you don't add exceptions and run it in RAM mode (the default). You can test discarding changes on reboot, servicing and memory usage of the system in something that is pretty close to WES7 EWF.

Comment: "It is not possible to install EWF on Windows 7 Home/Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate." This is incorrect. It is actually quite easy to install ewf in win7: http://www.mp3car.com/winnt-based/140081-ewf-on-windows-7-32-bit-or-64-bit-enhanced-write-filter.html

Comment: I meant "not possible" in that I couldn't ship it to a customer or get support for the solution, which is a bias I have.  Point taken that you can copy the files from Windows Embedded Standard 7